# How do I set up kmail in NixOS?

Tags: kde, nixos, kmail

I have these applications installed, via my configuration.nix:

```
 kdeApplications.kmail
 kdeApplications.kmail-account-wizard
 kdeApplications.kmailtransport
 kmail
 accounts-qt
```

and I think I have the right settings in Kmail for my gmail account (I used an application-specific password, since it looks like Google is still blocking akondai?).

But despite everything, I press "check mail" and it just does nothing—no errors or anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in `journalctl --user`?

Comment: The most relevant sounding message I can find is `Dec 21 13:14:25 jon-laptop org.freedesktop.Akonadi.Control[1183]: org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Subscriber "" disconnected`.